# Extracting values from rows which meet a condition in R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

## The data set

I have a big data frame with millions of rows and more than 20 columns. Let me first describe what the data is to make question more clear. The original data frame consists of locations, velocities and accelerations of 2169 vehicles during a 15 minute period. Each vehicle has a unique `Vehicle.ID`, an ID of the time frame in which it was observed i.e. `Frame.ID`, the velocity of vehicle in that frame i.e. `svel`, the acceleration of vehicle in that frame i.e. `sacc` and the class of that vehicle, `vehicle.class`, i.e. 1= motorcycle, 2= car, 3 = truck. These variables were recorded after every 0.1 seconds i.e. each frame is 0.1 seconds. Here are the first 6 rows:

```
> dput(head(df))
structure(list(Vehicle.ID = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Frame.ID = 133:138, 
    Vehicle.class = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Lane = c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), svel = c(37.29, 37.11, 36.96, 36.83, 36.73, 
    36.64), sacc = c(0.07, 0.11, 0.15, 0.19, 0.22, 0.25)), .Names = c("Vehicle.ID", 
"Frame.ID", "Vehicle.class", "Lane", "svel", "sacc"), row.names = 7750:7755, class = "data.frame")
```

There are some instances in vehicles' journey during the 15 minute recording period that they completely stop i.e. `svel==0`. This continues for some frames and then vehicles gain speed again. For the purpose of reproduciblity I am creating an example data set as follows:

```
x <- data.frame(Vehicle.ID = c(rep(10,5), rep(20,5), rep(30,5), rep(40,5), rep(50,5)),
                    vehicle.class = c(rep(2,10), rep(3,10),rep(1,5)),
                    svel = rep(c(1,0,0,0,3),5),
                    sacc = rep(c(0.3,0.001,0.001,0.002,0.5),5))
```

## What do I want to find?

As described above some vehicles stop and have zero velocity for some time but later accelerate to get up to speed. I want to find the acceleration, `sacc` they apply after having zero velocity for some time (moving from standstill position). This means that I should be able to look at the FIRST row AFTER the last frame in which `svel==0`. In the example data this means that the car (`vehicle.class==2`) having a `Vehicle.ID==10` had a velocity, `svel` equal to 1 as seen in the first row. Later, it stopped for 3 frames (3 consecutive rows) and then accelerated to velocity, `svel`, equal to 3. I want the acceleration `sacc` it applied in those 2 frames (rows 4 and 5 for vehicle 10, which come out to be 0.002 and 0.500). This means that for example data, following should be the output by `vehicle.class`:

```
output <- data.frame(Vehicle.ID = c(10,10,20,20,30,30,40,40,50, 50),
                     vehicle.class = c(2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,1),
                     xf = rep(c('l','f'),10),
                     sacc = rep(c(0.002,0.500),5))
```

`xf` identifies the last row `l` in which `svel==0` and `f` is the first one after that. I have tried using `plyr` and `for loop` to split by `vehicle.class` but am not sure how to extract the `sacc`.

## Note

1. `xf` should be a part of output. It is not in given data.
2. The original data frame `df` has 2169 vehicles, some stopped and
   some did not so not all vehicles had `svel==0`.
3. The vehicles which did stop didn't do it at the same time. Also, the
   number of rows in which `svel==0` is different vehicle to vehicle.

Comment: I suspect you'd be more likely to get useful responses if you describe the actual experiment and problem in more details. Currently it's hard to tell exactly what you need.

Comment: @hadley I've edited the question. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @Arun 1) There might be a case like that but highly unlikely. 2) Yes, there can be.

Comment: I think NA would be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but this works:

```
require(data.table)
x <- data.table(x)  ## much easier as data.table
x[, xf:='n']        ## create vector with 'n', neither first nor last

# create diff(svel) shifted upwards, 
# padding last observation with 0 to avoid cycling
x[, dsvel:=c(diff(svel, lag=1), 0), by=Vehicle.ID]

# svel is zero and dsvel positive at the last 0 value
x[svel==0 & dsvel > 0, xf:='l']

# there may be a better way to do this part
# get index of observation next to 'l'
# there is no risk of spilling to next Vehicle.ID,  
# because 'l' can only be second to last
i <- which(x$xf=='l') + 1
x[i, xf:='f']
```

That should give you the `xf` vector you want.

---

Edit from Arun: +1 @ilir, a very nice answer. Here's another way you could do it with the use of `data.table`'s inbuilt variables `.I` and `.N`:

```
idx = x[, {
            ix = tail(.I[svel==0L], 1);
            iy = (ix+1L)*((ix+1L) <= .I[.N] | NA) 
            list(idx = c(ix, iy))
          }, by = list(Vehicle.ID, vehicle.class)]$idx
```

You can now subset with `idx` add `l` and `f` with `:=` as follows:

```
ans <- x[idx][, xf := c("l", "f")]
    Vehicle.ID vehicle.class svel  sacc xf
 1:         10             2    0 0.002  l
 2:         10             2    3 0.500  f
 3:         20             2    0 0.002  l
 4:         20             2    3 0.500  f
 5:         30             3    0 0.002  l
 6:         30             3    3 0.500  f
 7:         40             3    0 0.002  l
 8:         40             3    3 0.500  f
 9:         50             1    0 0.002  l
10:         50             1    3 0.500  f
```

`.I` contains the row numbers of `x` for each group. `.N` contains the number of observations for each group. Please read `?data.table` for more.

`ix` gets the last occurrence of the 0. We subset the row number corresponding to the last 0, for each group, using `tail`.

`iy` normally should be the next entry = `ix+1L`. But since the 0 may be the last entry for some group, we check if it is so by comparing `(ix+1L) <= .I[.N]`. If it's FALSE that means `ix` is the last entry and so we've to output NA, else we've to output `(ix+1L)`.

HTH.

Comment: Glad it helped. You can probably do the same thing with `plyr`, I am just used to `data.table`. It really shines when you have large data and are memory-restricted. The syntax is intuitive but unusual (not similar to the rest of R)

Comment: @Arun That's why I said there may be a more elegant way :-). Very nice! The only difference I see is if there is more than one instance of acceleration from zero. You would only identify the last.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've come up with a reasonably elegant way of representing the
problem with dplyr. For each car, we're interested in the rows where
it's not stopped in this row, but was stopped in the previous row:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tbl_df(data.frame(
  id = c(rep(10, 5), rep(20, 5), rep(30, 5), rep(40, 5), rep(50, 5)), 
  class = c(rep(2, 10), rep(3, 10), rep(1, 5)), 
  svel = rep(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 3), 5), 
  sacc = rep(c(0.3, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.5), 5)
))

df %.% group_by(id) %.% 
  mutate(stopped = svel == 0) %.%
  filter(lag(stopped) == TRUE, stopped == FALSE)

#> Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
#> Groups: id
#> 
#>   id class svel sacc stopped
#> 1 10     2    3  0.5   FALSE
#> 2 20     2    3  0.5   FALSE
#> 3 30     3    3  0.5   FALSE
#> 4 40     3    3  0.5   FALSE
#> 5 50     1    3  0.5   FALSE
```

You could write this a little more compactly as

```
df %.% group_by(id) %.% 
  mutate(stopped = svel == 0) %.%
  filter(lag(stopped), !stopped)

#> Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
#> Groups: id
#> 
#>   id class svel sacc stopped
#> 1 10     2    3  0.5   FALSE
#> 2 20     2    3  0.5   FALSE
#> 3 30     3    3  0.5   FALSE
#> 4 40     3    3  0.5   FALSE
#> 5 50     1    3  0.5   FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I totally understand the question, but I think this is what you are after:

```
x <- data.frame(Vehicle.ID = c(rep(10,5), rep(20,5), rep(30,5), rep(40,5), rep(50,5)),
                vehicle.class = c(rep(2,10), rep(3,10),rep(1,5)),
                svel = rep(c(1,0,0,0,3),5),
                sacc = rep(c(0.3,0.001,0.001,0.002,0.5),5)
)

# find "l" rows, the last row for a given Vehicle.ID where svel==0
l <- FALSE
l[x$svel==0] <- !duplicated(x$Vehicle.ID[x$svel==0], fromLast=TRUE)
# extract all rows following an l row.
x[which(l) + 1, c(1, 2, 4)]
```

Comment: I've edited the question as your solution didn't work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
x = data.table(x)
output = x[xf == "f",sacc.after.zero := sacc, by = vehicle.class]
output[!is.na(sacc.after.zero),]
```

Comment: I've edited the question as your solution didn't work for me. Thanks